# Sitecore Custom Logger where each item represents its own log file

Tags: logging

There are many articles how to create your own logger and save a log file into a separate folder. I need something else.
My items represent the processors. It means I can click the button on the ribbon and run associated process by item id. Here is what I want to get.

1. When process is started, the new log file should be created where file name is \Data\logs[customfolder][itemid][timestamp].txt
2. Even process is finished and I run it again a new log file should be created.

Do you have an idea or solution how to implement it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: did you get the solution? I am also having the same query.

Comment: yes, I did. The solution is used in Sitecore Data Exchange Framework. Each time when pipeline batch is run a new log file is created.

Answer (score 5):

As Sitecore logging is just a wrapper on top of log4net, you should create an appender (and maybe logger) in your code (assuming that the "processor" you mention is some custom code). I found this solution on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833362/how-to-add-log4net-appender-in-runtime), but didn't test it myself. It is using the log4net api to create a `FileAppender` and set its properties. After creating the appender, you must add it to the logger you want to use for writing logs.

Comment: Thank you for respond. That is a something I've already seen. What I am interested more is  to reuse as much sitecore API as it possible. For example SitecoreLogFileAppender resolves the path but method MapPath is private and etc. If I create my custom appender and sitecore will change the default solution I need to care about updating my api. However, it is ok. I can use a reflection and sitecore factory or LoggerManager to get what i need from configuration.